# RTK Query updating the cache immediately after a mutation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm working with a Redux Toolkit createApi setup and have encountered an issue with the createItem endpoint triggering an unnecessary API call to fetch the basket.

My createItem mutation updates the basket and returns the updated data in the response. To ensure the cache reflects the update, I'm using invalidatesTags with the "Basket" tag and "LIST" ID.

Despite providing the updated basket in the response, the getBasket query is called again after createItem resolves. This seems redundant and unnecessary since the updated basket is already available.

```
export const basketApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "basketApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://localhost:5000/api/",
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Basket"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBasket: builder.query<Basket, void>({
      query: () => `basket`,
      providesTags: [{ type: "Basket", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    createItem: builder.mutation<Basket, { productId: number; qty?: number }>({
      query: ({ productId, qty }) => ({
        url: `Basket?productId=${productId}&quantity=${qty || 1}`,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags:  [{ type: "Basket", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
  }),
});
```

How can I prevent the unnecessary API call to getBasket after createItem when the response already includes the updated basket?

I found this way but not sure it is correct to call dispatch here:

```
export const basketApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "basketApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://localhost:5000/api/",
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Basket"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBasket: builder.query<Basket, void>({
      query: () => `basket`,
      providesTags: [{ type: "Basket", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    createItem: builder.mutation<Basket, { productId: number; qty?: number }>({
      query: ({ productId, qty }) => ({
        url: `Basket?productId=${productId}&quantity=${qty || 1}`,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result) => {
        store.dispatch(setBasket(result));
        return [];
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Redux Toolkit createApi setup, you can handle this scenario by using the `onSuccess` callback in the `createItem` endpoint. The `onSuccess` callback is triggered after a successful mutation, and you can use it to manually update the cache without triggering an additional API call.

See this way and how I made an adjustment to your createItem endpoint to handle this:

```js
export const basketApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "basketApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://localhost:5000/api/",
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Basket"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBasket: builder.query<Basket, void>({
      query: () => `basket`,
      providesTags: [{ type: "Basket", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    createItem: builder.mutation<Basket, { productId: number; qty?: number }>({
      query: ({ productId, qty }) => ({
        url: `Basket?productId=${productId}&quantity=${qty || 1}`,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: "Basket", id: "LIST" }],
      onQueryStarted: (variables, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
        // Now I used onQueryStarted to intercept the start of the mutation, you can use the onQueryStarted method
        // and manually update the cache without triggering an extra API call
        const cacheKey = basketApi.endpoints.getBasket.getKey();
        const originalData = queryFulfilled(cacheKey, {});
        const updatedData = { ...originalData, ...variables };

        dispatch(
          basketApi.endpoints.getBasket.onSuccess(updatedData, undefined, cacheKey)
        );
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....

I tried the solution but It is giving me:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSuccess' does not exist in type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<{ productId: number; qty?: number | undefined; }, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, void> & { ...; } & { ...; } & MutationExtraOptions<...>, "type">'.ts(2353)

I think it was removed in the newer versions of Toolkit

Comment: @Eli I have updated the code, I used the onQueryStarted now, you can check: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted for details

Comment: You may want to edit your post to refer to the correct function/property and documentation since `onSuccess` doesn't exist. Future readers shouldn't need to drill down to the comments to get the correct code/explanation.